During Login facing a problem where result is showing not allowed
I'm trying to login:
public async Task<bool> Login(LoginViewModel model)
{
    try
    {
        SignInResult result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, true, lockoutOnFailure: true);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);

            if (user != null)
            {
                var userTbResponse = _dbcontext.UserTb.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AspUserId == user.Id);

                if (userTbResponse != null)
                {
                    SessionManager.Email = user.Email;
                    SessionManager.UserId = userTbResponse.UserId;
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError("Error occurred during login: " + ex.Message, ex);
        throw;
    }
}

but result is showing not allowed

After checking the PasswordSignInAsync source codes, we could find it will call CheckPasswordSignInAsync method, inside the CheckPasswordSignInAsync it will call var error = await PreSignInCheck(user); , inside the CanSignInAsync method it will return the SignInResult.NotAllowed.
 protected virtual async Task<SignInResult?> PreSignInCheck(TUser user)
    {
        if (!await CanSignInAsync(user))
        {
            return SignInResult.NotAllowed;
        }
        if (await IsLockedOut(user))
        {
            return await LockedOut(user);
        }
        return null;
    }

It CanSignInAsync, it contains a lot of conditions like below, so you could check the account has passed the email confirm or not.
public virtual async Task<bool> CanSignInAsync(TUser user)
{
    if (Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail && !(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user)))
    {
        Logger.LogDebug(EventIds.UserCannotSignInWithoutConfirmedEmail, "User cannot sign in without a confirmed email.");
        return false;
    }
    if (Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber && !(await UserManager.IsPhoneNumberConfirmedAsync(user)))
    {
        Logger.LogDebug(EventIds.UserCannotSignInWithoutConfirmedPhoneNumber, "User cannot sign in without a confirmed phone number.");
        return false;
    }
    if (Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount && !(await _confirmation.IsConfirmedAsync(UserManager, user)))
    {
        Logger.LogDebug(EventIds.UserCannotSignInWithoutConfirmedAccount, "User cannot sign in without a confirmed account.");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

